# Custom ringtone sounds good on computer, can't be heard on phone

Tags: sampling, sound

I did a ringtone using Audacity and then used [this website](http://online-audio-converter.com) to convert to mp3. I sent this mp3 file to a friend who said he couldn't hear it well. I have an iPhone so I converted it to m4r. Both the mp3 and m4r files play nicely in my computer. However, when I imported it to my iPhone SE, only certain parts could be heard. Here it is if you want to try it

https://soundcloud.com/jpproducoes/test-ringtone/s-TmLZ7

Open it on your computer, then open the same link on your phone (you can use soundcloud, the result will be the same). On the phone it will sound much more distorted, and some parts won't be audible. I believe this might be due to sampling rate problems, but I am not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Try importing into iTunes and play it through the music player on your phone using headphones

Comment: The problem is probably mainly the size of mobile phone speakers, which I think are mainly bad at producing low frequency sound (however my earphones are also small, so one would think those would be bad at it as well, but at least mine aren't).

Comment: try a smaller bit-rate maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Plug your phone into some large speakers.  If you can hear the tone much better, then the problem might be the small size of the speakers on the iPhone, which roll off low frequencies.

To prevent this, make sure any low pitched notes in your ringtone are made with timbres rich in strong higher overtones.

Added: If you create a ringtone from a stereo file, it's probably best if both channels contain exactly the same data.

Comment: Plugging hearphones into my iPhone did the trick... The ringtone is made with samples. Does this mean the only way of fixing it is changing the pitch of the singer's voice?

Comment: Found the culprit! The original file was stereo, and it had to be converted to mono for the ringtone. However the left and right channels cancelled out in those inaudible parts.

Answer (score 0):

The ringtone was made with samples. The sound in these samples was recorded in stereo, and the left and right channels cancelled each other out. Phones play tracks in mono, and therefore it was playing the cancelled waveform. Splitting the channels, inverting one, and then converting to mono did the trick.

Comment: If you invert a waveform of which the 1st half causes cancellation, now the 2nd half will cancel.